# What did I just add an application to?

Tags: facebook

I just did the step to add Facebook to my Dropbox account in order to get a bit of [extra space](https://www.dropbox.com/free), but then I wanted to undo it as I do not want Dropbox to make posts to my wall.

However, the application doesn't look like a normal application (e.g. stays on the list on the left... I only got to it after finding it's ID and clicking remove).

After this, out of curiosity, I wanted to add it again... (Don't ask me why!), so I clicked the `Add to my Page` link on the left hand bar, and I only had two options, first was a page I don't use and the second was `App` which I thought meant "Add as an App" or similar.

I clicked this and I can not see any way to undo it, or what it even did.

Here is a picture from the first application I could find... Substitute `Iframe Apps` for `Dropbox` and that is what I saw : (FYI, if I do it now from the Dropbox page, App is no longer listed)

[image]

After looking for ages, I am clueless! Anyone know what I did?

Comment: Being a SuperUser person, it feels naughty asking a question about Facebook!

Comment: btw, @Wil you can link to facebook &  chose not to post the message

Answer (score 1):

I repeated your steps as follows,

1. Went to [Dropbox](https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=210019893730) application page
2. Selected add to page (note, the page is not your profile so you removed it from your profile first time)
   [image: A Page to add the Dropbox app]
3. Investigated the app and it was found to be an app that I used to experiment with a page. But notice the app page is not listed as a switch option to use Facebook as a page
   [image: Using Facebook as a user]

Head over to the [developers section](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) and you will see what app you had forgotten about. I found out that it was an app that I tried to associate with a page but forgot all about it.

So in summary, you added Dropbox to a page of an app that you may have forgotten about.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove an app from your personal profile, go to **Account** (in the upper right corner) and choose **Privacy Settings**.  Then under **Apps and Websites** click on **Edit your settings**.  To the right of **Apps you use** click on **Edit Settings** and click the **X** to the right of any app you want to remove.

The **Add to My Page** link is for adding an app to a page for which you are an administrator, including a fan page or an application profile page if you have your own Facebook app.  It is not for adding an app to your personal profile.  (Facebook no longer allows adding third party application tabs to a personal profile.)

The unnamed App looks like it is your own Facebook App, or one for which you are an administrator.  If you didn't know you had an app then you should be able to click on the icon (the gears) to go to its profile page.  From there, if you see the app you don't want on a tab you can click on Edit under the tabs and then click the X next to the tab you want to remove.  Or you can click on Edit App which also includes a section listing apps that have been added as tabs on your page, and a Remove App button to remove any that you don't want.

Comment: I am not the administrator for anything other than my one page which is not public... I am not an admin of any apps :/

Comment: Did you go to the app profile page and do you see an Edit App button in the upper right corner?

Comment: I am there right now - I don't have Dropbox and I don't see anything called "app" and yet, I still get that option on other applications! :/